# overlapping JPanels in the GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jpanel

I am using BorderLayout in my application. I have a main panel to which I add two JPanels at the center. I want one of them to be transparent.
My code is :

```
 mainPanel = new JPanel();
 mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
 mainPanel.add(getGraphPaneScrollPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
 mainPanel.add(getSituationPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Code for these two functions is :

```
public JScrollPane getGraphPaneScrollPane() {
    if (graphPaneScrollPane == null) {
        graphPaneScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        graphPaneScrollPane.setViewportView(getGraphEditorPane());
    }
    return graphPaneScrollPane;
}
private JScrollPane getSituationPanel(){
    if(situationPanel == null){
        logs.debug("Initializing Situation Panel");

        situationPanel = new JScrollPane();

        situationLabel = new JLabel("");
        situationLabel.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
        situationLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        situationLabel.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
        situationLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        situationLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));
        situationLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        situationLabel.setOpaque(true);
        situationLabel.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);

        situationPanel.setViewportView(situationLabel); 

    } 

    return situationPanel;
}
```

Now I want situationPanel to be transparent and getGraphPaneScrollPane to be above that in the GUI, because getGraphPaneScrollPane is the canvas, which I use to draw nodes.

Comment: This can be done using a `CardLayout`

Comment: Ok. But my problem is that I am making changes to an application that is already built. So making changes to the layout is the last thing I want. I am not sure what other code it will break.
Can't this be done by making one panel transparent or something like that?

Comment: The application that is already built, whose is it? Is it your program?

Comment: to add to the description of the problem :
my situation panel contains a label which has some text on it. So what I want basically is to merge two panels so that it will have text background and I can draw over it.

Comment: Consider using a JLayeredPane to layer one JPanel on top of another.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels : No. It's built by someone else, I am just merging these two tabs.

Answer (score 1):

> I want situationPanel to be transparent and getGraphPaneScrollPane to be above that in the GUI,

The panel that is on top is the panel that needs to be transparent. If the panel on top is opaque then you will never see the panel under the top panel.

> So making changes to the layout is the last thing I want.

Well that is what you are going to need to do. You can't just add two panels to one panel and expect it to work the way you want it to. Most Swing layout managers are designed to lay out components in two dimensions, not on top of one another.

Your current code is:

```
mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
mainPanel.add(getGraphPaneScrollPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
mainPanel.add(getSituationPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

You could try using the OverlayLayout, it is designed to lay out panels on top of on another. The code should be something like:

```
JPanel overlay = new JPanel();
overlay.setLayout( new OverlayLayout(overlay) );
overlay.add(getSituationPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER); // add transparent panel first
overlay.add(getGraphPaneScrollPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
mainPanel.add(overlay);
```

Comment: Ok. I'll try this one out. But now with this one I still have a problem of transparency, as in I have to following right? : situationPanel.setOpaque(false);

Comment: I got it without using OverLayLayout as well. I just had to make correct panes opaque and others transparent. And I have to use repaint more frequently.

Comment: @tejas, not a good solution. You should not need to use repaint(). Swing has a well defined painting mechanism. This is a hack that will cause you problems in the future. It is so simple to use layout managers properly.

Comment: Oh ! Is that why my overlapping gets lost everytime I mouse click on the panel? and I have to repaint then.

Comment: I don't know what will happen since I haven't seen your exact code. All I know is you can get weird results and you keep adding hacks to your program to get it working.

Comment: Oh ! I'll check and get back to you. Thanks for the insight though.